# How to just print the pattern strings to the pattern ending point

Tags: awk

In my file, there are a lot of 'update' SQL statement, and I want to get the desired output like the bottom of the question.
The `file.awk` failed.

Can you help me make it better?

#### file

```
-- [1] Wed May  7 07:30:05 2014

-- DDDDDDDD DDDD DDDDD
-- KKKKK KKKKK KKKKK KKKKKK
update   "SCOTT"."TABLE" t 
set "KKKK"='01',"BBBBBB"='20140507073000   ' 
where "AAAAA" = 1 
and "BBBBBB"='20140502180500   ';

-- [2] Wed May  7 07:30:05 2014

-- FFFFFFF DDDD DDDDD
-- KKKKK KKKKK KKKKK KKKKKK
update   "SCOTT"."TABLE2" t 
set "KKKK"='01',"BBBBBB"='20140507073000   ' 
where "AAAAA" = 5 
and "BBBBBB"='20160502180500   ';
```

#### Awk script ( file.awk )

```
BEGIN {
      matched = 0;
}
/] /,/;/ {                       
           if (/update:$/) {
                         splitHipen=$2;
                         split(splitHipen,splitHipenArr,".");
                         printf "%s#",substr(splitHipenArr[1],2,length(splitHipenArr[1])-2);   #TABLE_OWNER
                         printf "%s#",substr(splitHipenArr[2],2,length(splitHipenArr[2])-2);   #TABLE_NAME

              { matched = 1 } matched { print }

             }

      } 

END {
}
```

#### Desired Output

```
SCOTT#TABLE#update   "SCOTT"."TABLE" t 
    set "KKKK"='01',"BBBBBB"='20140507073000   ' 
    where "AAAAA" = 1 
    and "BBBBBB"='20140502180500   ';   
SCOTT#TABLE2#update   "SCOTT"."TABLE2" t 
    set "KKKK"='01',"BBBBBB"='20140507073000   ' 
    where "AAAAA" = 5 
    and "BBBBBB"='20160502180500   ';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/^--/ {next;}  # Skip comments
/update/ { schema=$2""$1;
           gsub(/[". ]+/, "#", schema);
           print substr(schema, 2), $2, $3;
           next} # Re-arrange fields
1  # Default action, just print
```

Comment: Ramana: What should I do for printing 'Wed' as well without just skipping it?

Comment: I was able to print other pattern as well with the code below. u||/^update/  { u=1;
                printf "%s",$0
     }  Thank you so much !!!!
     /;$/&&u{u=0;print ""}

Answer (score 0):

```html
'BEGIN{RS=";"}{sub(".*update","update")}{if (/update/){
                         splitHipen=$2;
                         split(splitHipen,splitHipenArr,".");
                         printf "%s#",substr(splitHipenArr[1],2,length(splitHipenArr[1])-2);   #TABLE_OWNER
                         printf "%s#",substr(splitHipenArr[2],2,length(splitHipenArr[2])-2);   #TABLE_NAME

              printf("%s;\n",$0)

             }}'
```

Comment: Define ; as line separator in BEGIN block.
Delete content before update using substitute command.
After formatting, print string with ; and newline.
You dont need END block if there is no content

Comment: Thank you. With your script, I can see 2 'update' statement correctly. However, the pattern starts  "] " (first line) and ends with ';' so there are 2 block to parse in the above file. when I tried BEGIN{RS=";"}
/] /,/;/ {  .... your script, it just shows the last 'update' statement. Can you help me print the all of 'update' statements with the pattern?

Comment: You dont need any other pattern as it deletes anything before update.
Can you paste out where it failed?

Comment: Oh. I think my question was wrong. It is not for printing only 'update' statement. Actually, I need to print other items as well like Wed#SCOTT#TABLE .....

Comment: Sorry for confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Ramana's answer.

```html
/^-- / && !/]/{next}  # Skip comments which doesn't contain ]
/]/{schema=" "$3;next} # Store Day in variable schema
/update/ { schema=schema""$2""$1;
           gsub(/[". ]+/, "#", schema);
           print substr(schema, 2), $2, $3;
           next} # Re-arrange fields
1
```